# Show/Hide the login and logout buttons

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs, middleware, express-session

I'm currently using MySQL and EJS. I was trying to show/hide buttons based on user authentication, but it didn't work.

**connection.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');
require('dotenv').config();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB,
});

const query = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);

exports.query = query;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const { query } = require('../DB/connection');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const sessionConfig = {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    },
};

app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('user/login');
});

app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        const result = await query('SELECT * from users WHERE username = ?', [
            username,
        ]);
        if (!result || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password))) {
            return res.status(401).send('Wrong');
        } else {
            
            const id = result[0].userId;
            req.session.id = id;
            req.session.loggedin = true
            req.flash('success', 'welcome back!');
            res.redirect('/success')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.redirect('/error');
    }
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serving on port 3000');
});
```

**login.ejs**

```
<form action="/login" method="POST" class="validated-form" novalidate>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
</form>
```

**navbar.ejs**

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Restaurant</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about">View Reversation</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <% if(!locals.session.loggedin) {%>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
                <% } else {%>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I logged in successfully, but the login and register buttons were visible, and the logout was invisible.

I'm looking for a way to hide the login and register buttons and show the logout button when logged in successfully. Conversely, show the login and register buttons and hide the logout button when logged out successfully.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `res.locals.session.loggedin = req.session.loggedin;` to your middleware function

```
   app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        res.locals.session.loggedin = req.session.loggedin; 
        res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
        res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
        next();
    });
```